# Why do I get "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable"?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm making a "dog register" where you can save information about dogs and bid on dogs up for auction etc. 
I am a beginner and was recently told that array list should be private, this information got me in some trouble.

I got a class named `Auction` where you can store bids, I made a get method in this class to use in the main class. It works on every line except one in my method where you can delete a user.

```
private void deleteUser()
{
    System.out.println("Enter the name of the user: ");
    String name = input.nextLine().toLowerCase().trim();

    User deleteUser = getUser(name);
    while (name.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Error. Enter the name of the user: ");
        name = input.nextLine().toLowerCase().trim();

        deleteUser = getUser(name);
    }

    if (deleteUser == null) {
        userException();
        return;
    }

    for (Auction a : auctionRegister) {
        ArrayList<Bid> bids = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Bid b : a.getBidList()) {
            if (b.getUser() != deleteUser) {
                bids.add(b);
            }
        }
        a.getBidList() = bids;
    }

    if (deleteUser.getDogList() != null) {

        for (Dog dog : deleteUser.getDogList()) {
            dogRegister.remove(dog);
        }
    }

    userRegister.remove(deleteUser);
    System.out.println("User " + deleteUser.getUserName() + " is removed");
}
```

I get the error message on this line("The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable"):

```
a.getBidList() = bids;
```

Everything worked when i had the array list public so my question is, how do i solve this?

Comment: You can only assign (`=`) to variables. `a.getBidList()` is not a variable. You probably want a setter. `a.setBidList(bids)`

Comment: Java doesn't have reference semantics, so `getBidList` returns a *value* that you change to some other value, but then you throw the changed value away, so what's the point? (Of course, as the compiler is telling you, it's not legal. But if it was, it wouldn't do anything. If `sqrt(5)=3;` was legal, it wouldn't change the square root of five to be three. It would compute the square root of five, replace it with three, and then throw away the three.)

Comment: Thank you. @Michael I created a setter, which looks like this:                            public ArrayList <Bid> setBidList(Bid bid){
  return this.bidRegister= setBidList(bid);
  
 }   but that caused another problem, instead of the previous error message, I got "The method setBidList(Bid) in the type Auction is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<Bid>)" in my main class. how do i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Java has 2 varieties of 'buckets' in which to store information. One variety is a *variable*, the other is a *constant*. Both varieties let you look in the bucket to see the contents. A variable also allows you to you replace the current contents of the bucket.

Your syntax , `a.setBidList()` is a method call, which is constant. You can read from it but you can't assign a new value to it. Since you have it on the left side of an assignment statement, you are asking Java to do something it can't do.